# Display Field for select item in the list grid

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

Hello all 
I am using smart gwt 2.2 on windows with mozilla browser.

I am using a  list grid with two fields.
I set the editor type of second field to SelectItem.
In that select item I am rendering a grid.
For select item I set the value field and the display field.

But after the select any item from select item it is display value field.
I am also attaching the code for it.

code for grid

```
public void initializeGrid() {
  ListGrid grid = new ListGrid();
  setGridProperty(grid);
  grid.setFields(getGridFields());
  grid.setData(getGridData());
  getSmartContainer().addChild(grid);
 }

 private static ListGridRecord[] getGridData() {
  ListGridRecord record = new ListGridRecord();
  record.setAttribute("id", "");
  record.setAttribute("name", "");

                ListGridRecord record1 = new ListGridRecord();
  record1.setAttribute("id", "");
  record1.setAttribute("name", "");

  return new ListGridRecord[] { record, record1 };
 }

 private static void setGridProperty(ListGrid grid) {
  grid.setWidth("90%");
  grid.setHeight(125);
  grid.setCanEdit(true);
  grid.setEditEvent(ListGridEditEvent.CLICK);
  grid.setEditByCell(true);
  grid.setAlternateRecordStyles(true);
  grid.setShowAllRecords(true);
 }

 private static ListGridField[] getGridFields() {
  ListGridField field = new ListGridField("id");
  FormItem item = new TextItem();
  field.setEditorType(item);

  ListGridField field1 = new ListGridField("name");
  SelectItem item1 = new SelectItem("name");
  setPropertyForSelectitem(item1);
  DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
  dataSource.setClientOnly(true);
  item1.setOptionDataSource(dataSource);
  setDataForSelectItem(dataSource);
  field1.setEditorType(item1);

                return new ListGridField[] { field, field1 };
 }
```

Code for select item

```
public static void setDataForSelectItem(DataSource dataSource) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   ListGridRecord record = new ListGridRecord();
   record.setAttribute("id", "1");
   record.setAttribute("name", "name" + i);
   record.setAttribute("address", "address" + i);
   dataSource.addData(record);
  }
 }

 private static void setPropertyForSelectitem(SelectItem item) {
  item.setPickListFields(getFieldsForSelectItem());
  item.setWidth(150);
  item.setValueField("id");
  item.setDisplayField("name");
  item.setPickListWidth(250);
 }

 private static ListGridField[] getFieldsForSelectItem() {
  ListGridField idField = new ListGridField("id");
  ListGridField nameField = new ListGridField("name");
  ListGridField addField = new ListGridField("address");
  return new ListGridField[] {idField,nameField,addField };
 }
```

[/CODE]

After drawing this grid it is rendering value field for the select item, but i want to render the name (as it is the display field for the select item).

Same select item I used in the dynamic form but it is working well at that place, but for the grid it is not working well.
Please Help.
Thanks